Is there any specific notion in Pakistan's public sphere about the military of Pakistan?
Is there any such notion in Pakistan's public sphere that

Pakistan's Army is the only savior or custodian of the Pakistani state
Pakistan's Army is the only institution for which the Pakistani state has not disintegrated (more)
Pakistan will disintegrate if the Pakistan Army doesn't control Pakistan's civilian politics

?
If so, are these notions propagated or promoted by the Pakistan Army or someone else?

Not my DV, but I'm not sure what #2 is even supposed to mean. As for #3, perhaps: ‘it is time to prioritise governance over democracy’ reportedly said one general. It's certainly been the case sometimes in the past that they've invoked something-something to take over.

@IVFcomesfromthetip, but I'm not sure what #2 is even supposed to mean. --- edited.

You mean something similar to the role Turkey's armed forces were claiming from the 60s to the 90s?  And do you mean to ask if there is a constitutional basis for that position?  I don't know if the Q, as stated, is very clear.  Or if it can easily made more clear.  However, it seems to me that a Q asking what "context" gives Pakistan's armed forces the "right" to intervene so much in their domestic politics is, innately, of great interest here.  I am being deliberately vague with "right" and "context":  there is no need to fine-tune the terms, really, they can be defined in answers.

Too speculative to be worth an answer, but... Not to disrespect mainstream Islam in any way, Pakistan's situation seems to be somewhat akin to Algeria, Egypt, Turkey, etc... :  the armed forces have claimed for themselves the role of protecting the nation from extremists (and India too, let's not forget) and at least some of the population are likely worried enough to tolerate it.  That doesn't mean the army is sincere, is widely believed, doesn't abuse it or even does the job well.  It just means that this is likely to be a big "notion in the public sphere".

"Pakistan's Army is the only savior of the power of Pakistan's Army." :-)

@ItalianPhilosopher, You mean something similar to the role Turkey's armed forces were claiming from the 60s to the 90s? --- Yes, if that was the case in Turkey back then. And do you mean to ask if there is a constitutional basis for that position? --- No. However, it seems to me that a Q asking what "context" gives Pakistan's armed forces the "right" to intervene so much in their domestic politics is, innately, of great interest here. --- Yes but I will post a separate question for that.

what would be a "reputable source" in this context?

@IVFcomesfromthetip, https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/understanding-pakistans-military/

Sure, but that was written 14 years ago. In the meantime Musharraf was convicted etc. I thought you wanted something more recent.

@IVFcomesfromthetip, https://www.orfonline.org/research/cause-and-effect-the-factors-that-make-pakistans-military-a-political-force

@user366312 If that is a reputabel source, maybe you could briefly summarise what it says and to what extent it does of does not answer yopur question?

Something along the lines of 3 has been invoked from time to time, e.g.

The Supreme Court ruling on May 12, 2000 that the military takeover in October 1999 was justified under the "doctrine of necessity".

More recently that Court appeared to be more willing to stand up to the military but last year the seemed backtrack on some issues like allowing military trials for civilians rioting in army installations at least. (Final decision on that still pending, apparently.)
And this summer, reportedly:

Chief Justice Qazi Faez Isa on Tuesday equated the ‘doctrine of necessity’ with the ‘justice principle’, saying successive military takeovers had been legalised in the past using the same principle, as embodied in the maxim ‘Salus Populi Supreme Lex Esto’ (the welfare of people should be the supreme law).

(Reading the rest of the piece, it seems though that Isa mostly said that to criticize an intuitive notion of justice, not grounded in the constitution. On the other hand, the topic at hand there seems to have been whether the Supreme Court can overrule the Election Commission of Pakistan, on the the non-trivial topic of banning Imran Khan's party [PTI]. Which some of the other justices felt was an injustice they had to consider. Actually, the case at hand seems to have been something stemming from that ban [not the ban itself], namely the apparent procedural deadlocks that a large number of independent parliamentarians created, as the constitution had apparently not accounted for that possibility. But at least some of the other justices felt the occasion allowed them to address the ban itself, which led to that rebuke from Isa.)
Also, last year, one general might have said

it is time to prioritise governance over democracy.

